# How to format date for BigCommerce blog post

Tags: api, bigcommerce

I keep getting errors while trying to create blog posts via API calls to BigCommerce, due to the published_date_iso8601 field.

This field expects the date string in this kind of format "5/18/2018 1:26:42 PM", as per the docs here: https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/1b41aac9b9f54-create-a-blog-post

My data has the dates in this format: "2022-05-12T13:09:23-07:00"
I am using Javascript, and I have tried multiple ways to transform the format, but no success so far.
I have tried built-in JS Date methods

```
const originalDate = "2022-05-12T13:09:23-07:00"
const newDate = new Date(originalDate).toISOString()
```

I have tried using Moment

```
const originalDate = "2022-05-12T13:09:23-07:00"
const newDate = moment(
                originalDate
            ).format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss A')
```

And multiple variations of formatting besides those 2 examples, but I still can't get the post to go through. The error is only a 400 code with no message.
Anyone know how to format this?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `published_date` field and `new Date('2022-05-12T13:09:23-07:00').toUTCString()`?

Hopefully, this should work for you.

A